# Need recommendation of name of human lotion or cream that is safe for cats to lick!

Tags: cats, safety

I have a cat who loves to kiss me by licking my hands, arms, face when I am near or petting her. I am wondering if anyone has heard of a human hand or body lotion that is safe for cats to lick? My hands and arms are dry, so I like to wear lotion! I just want to make sure that kitty is safe. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered simply not using skin lotion anymore, and letting your body reset to an equilibrium where it doesn't need skin lotion to maintain its skin? If you habitually use skin lotion, then your body will adjust itself by making the skin dryer to compensate, forcing you to continue to use skin lotion.

Comment: I agree with making your own! Shea butter would be a good natural option as well. Super moisturizing and safe for animals.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas on making my own hand cream! I do have coconut oil -here maybe I'll try a little of that alone-Hopefully not too greasy. 
I also appreciated the suggestion about not using lotion so that your body could moisturize itself and not get dependent, but my experience has been that as we age, we lose oils and elasticity and the skin needs a little help. I'm convinced that my face looks as good as it does (few wrinkles) because I've been using creams through the years (And good genetics! Thanks, Mom & Dad)!I appreciate all the thoughts and suggestions. Thank you!!

Comment: I am sorry but this question has to be closed because of reasons mentioned in [this Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad).

Answer (score 0):

You are a good cat parent! There are so many lotions out there that are concerning. You could try making your own hand moisturizer out of coconut oil, or jojoba oil mixed with a bit of glycerine. Have them at room temp and use a wire whisk to emulsify. You could try other combos to see if they work for you. In a pinch, plain Vaseline might work, although it is greasy.